# Loading a PE32 executable DLL Intel 80386 into a c# program

Tags: dll, c#, dll-injection, pe32

I'm new here so I'm sorry if this isn't the right section for my question.

I'm reverse engineering a software that's written in .net 3.5 c# which loads a weird dynamic dll, which has an important functionality of decrypting / encrypting strings. I tried to make a c# program and import the dlls but visual studio complains about invalid / unsupported dll.

Here is some output and info:

```
targetframework: .Net Framework v3.5
```

```
FileAnalyzer.dll:  PE32 executable (DLL) (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

the .net software loads it and hooks its functions like this:

```
 public class FileDataCtrlWrap
  {
    [DllImport("FileDataCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool GetPersonalSettingsFolder(byte[] buffer, uint type);

    [DllImport("FileDataCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool GetSettingsFolder(byte[] buffer, uint type);

    [DllImport("FileDataCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool GetSnapShotFolder(byte[] buffer);

    [DllImport("FileDataCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern bool GetSnapShotPath(string cameraName, byte[] buffer);

    [DllImport("FileDataCtrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Encrypt(string intput, StringBuilder output);
...
...
..etc
```

1. How is this .net program loading a pe32 dll?
2. Is it possible to replicate this behavior? If not what are the alternatives?

the dll file can be found [here](https://filebin.net/sqxsz86tmh63fdq2)

Comment: Is your app targeted to x86 or x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load 32bit Dlls in 64bit Processes

Solution: build a 32bit App or write an external 32bit prozess(yes a EXE) that loads the DLL and communication with that process using Pipes or TCP/IP from your 64bit app

btw: the first Dlls name is FileAnalyzer.dll, in the Code is FileDataCtrl.dll?